# specifying same column more than once in order by in spark sql returns different result when same column specified once in order

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks

```
q1:  select distinct y.c1,y.c2,y.c6,
    y.c3,y.c5
    max(case when  y.c3 is null and y.c4='N'  and y.c5 <>'Cancelled' and p.c6 is not null 
    then 'Y' else y.c4 end) as c4, 
    min(case when  y.c3 is null and y.c4='N'  and y.c5 <>'Cancelled' and p.c6 is not null 
    then p.c6 else y.c4_dt end) as c4_dt 
    from table1 y left join 
    (select distinct c6,c1 from table1 f 
    inner join 
    (select distinct c2 from table2 where c4 is null) g on f.c2=g.c2 where f.c4='Y' 
    )p
    on p.c1=y.c1  
    and  y.c4='N' 
    and cast(add_months(p.c6, -12) as date) <= y.c6 and y.c6<=p.c6
    group by 
    y.c1,y.c2,y.c6,y.c6,
    y.c3,y.c5



q2:select distinct y.c1,y.c2,y.c6,
    y.c3,y.c5
    max(case when  y.c3 is null and y.c4='N'  and y.c5 <>'Cancelled' and p.c6 is not null 
    then 'Y' else y.c4 end) as c4, 
    min(case when  y.c3 is null and y.c4='N'  and y.c5 <>'Cancelled' and p.c6 is not null 
    then p.c6 else y.c4_dt end) as c4_dt 
    from table1 y left join 
    (select distinct c6,c1 from table1 f 
    inner join 
    (select distinct c2 from table2 where c4 is null) g on f.c2=g.c2 where f.c4='Y' 
    )p
    on p.c1=y.c1  
    and  y.c4='N' 
    and cast(add_months(p.c6, -12) as date) <= y.c6 and y.c6<=p.c6
    group by 
    y.c1,y.c2,y.c6,
    y.c3,y.c5
```